# C/C++ preprocessor directive for handing compilation errors

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor-directive

The title might be somewhat confusing, so I'll try to explain.

Is there a preprocessor directive that I can encapsulate a piece of code with, so that if this piece of code contains a compilation error, then some other piece of should be compiled instead?

Here is an example to illustrate my motivation:

```
#compile_if_ok
    int a = 5;
    a += 6;
    int b = 7;
    b += 8;
#else
    int a = 5;
    int b = 7;
    a += 6;
    b += 8;
#endif
```

The above example is not the problem I am dealing with, so please do not suggest specific solutions.

### UPDATE:

Thank you for all the negative comments down there.

Here is the exact problem, perhaps someone with a little less negative approach will have an answer:

I'm trying to decide during compile-time whether some variable `a` is an array or a pointer.

I've figured I can use the fact that, unlike pointers, an array doesn't have an L-value.

So in essence, the following code would yield a compilation error for an array but not for a pointer:

```
int a[10];
a = (int*)5;
```

Can I somehow "leverage" this compilation error in order to determine that `a` is an array and not a pointer, **without stopping the compilation process**?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you write something that wouldn't compile? O_o I think maybe we need to know your specific problem...

Comment: Preprocessing happens before compiler errors like that are found.

Comment: I would talk jibrish if it made sense, but it won't right?

Comment: You most likely have a design flaw deeper down in your program, which makes your question sound totally nonsense and fool. Review your design, something is wrong with your approach.

Comment: Meta-exception handling! `static try { /* ... */ } static catch ( ... ) { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: No - there's nothing like that in the toolchain. But you might be able to craft a makefile or build script that did this (if one compile fails, try again with a `-D` that will cause the other preprocessor conditional to become active).  However build scripts are already often arcane enough to drive people insane - what would be the point of adding this craziness?

Comment: This question seems like a prime candidate for an XY problem.

Comment: XY-Problem. Are you, by any chance, trying to approach the problem of writing code that compiles on multiple compilers?

Comment: Preprocessing come before compilation, the compiler will see the first or second part of your if/else statement.

Comment: @chris: Compilers are not obligated to complete preprocessing before the rest of compilation. In GCC (e.g., Apple GCC 4.2.1), compiling a program containing the two lines `foo bar;` and `#error "abc"` with `gcc -Wfatal-errors` yields an error message for the first line and not the second. A compiler could support a feature such as the OP requests as an extension.

Comment: Is this C or C++? Because the answer varies considerably.

Comment: Need an answer to both. Also, please note that I have revised the question in order to explain the exact purpose (which is **NOT** running on multiple platform, as "conjectured" by some of the answers below). Thanks

Comment: You may use template to have special code depending of the fact a variable is a array or a pointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, Interesting, and the behaviour you describe is the same with Clang 3.5, but not GCC 4.8.1. I should have figured there was a possibility for a compiler to do this, but I've never heard of anything that did.

Comment: You should really pick one language. If you need a solution that works in C, then tag this as C.

Comment: I vaguely recall some Stack Overflow question, and a good answer, about testing whether an identifier was a pointer or an array. However, I cannot find it? Can anybody else? I think it was within the past year, maybe a bit longer.

Comment: Your updated question still doesn't make sense. Why do you not know the type of `a`? You should know whether it's a pointer or an array from its declaration. If it's a template type, then sure, you can do this easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

It's not uncommon for large C++ (and other-language) projects to have a "configuration" stage designed into their build system to attempt compilation of different snippets of code, generating a set of preprocessor definitions indicating which ones worked, so that the compilation of the project proper can then use the preprocessor definitions in `#ifdef`/`#else`/`#endif` statements to select between alternatives.  For many UNIX/Linux software packages, running the "./configure" script coordinates this.  You can read about the `autoconf` tool that helps create such scripts at http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/

Comment: Nice insight - this is pretty much exactly what `./configure` does.

Comment: Thanks, but running on different platforms is not the purpose of my question here; question revised to explain the exact purpose, can you please have a second look?

Comment: @barakmanos have you considered using http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_array ?

Comment: Stop recommending autofools to people, guys. Seriously. Let's just let it die a slow, painful death.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in standard C. However, many command shells make this fairly simple. For example, in bash, you can write a script such as:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Try to compile the program with Code0 defined.    
if cc -o program -DCode0= "$*"; then
    # That worked, do nothing extra. (Need some command here due to bash syntax.)
    /bin/true
else
    # The first compilation failed, try without Code0 defined.
    cc -o program "$*"
fi

./program
```

Then your source code can test whether `Code0` is defined:

```
#if defined Code0
    foo bar;
#else
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
        printf("Hello, world.\n");
        return 0;
    }
#endif
```

However, there are usually better ways to, in effect, make source code responsive to the environment or the target platform.

Answer (score 1):

C11 _Generic macros might be able to handle this. If not, though, you're screwed in C.

Not in the C++ preprocessor. In C++ you can easily use overload resolution or a template or even expression SFINAE or anything like that to execute a different function depending on if `a` is an array or not. That is still occurring after preprocessing though.

If you need one that is both valid C and valid C++, the best you can do is `#ifdef __cplusplus` and handle it that way. Their common subset (which is mostly C89) definitely does not have something that can handle this at any stage of compilation.

Comment: I downvoted you because C99 does not have _Generic macros (that's new in C11) and because you did not give any clue as to how to do this in C++.

Comment: Really? Cause I had like, a paragraph, covering his options in C++. So you downvoted me because I mixed up C99 and C11? Nice revenge downvote there.

Comment: I down voted you because you had incorrect information and because your paragraph says nothing to someone who presumably doesn't know what SFINAE means, let alone how to use it.

Comment: It's not my job to write him a book about what SFINAE is. It's more than enough for him to find what he needs on his own.

Answer (score 1):

On the updated question :

If you're writing C++, use templates...

Specifically, to test the type of a variable you have helpers : std::enable_if, std::is_same, std::is_pointer, etc

See the type support module : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types

Comment: Any chance to avoid the use of `std` (or any other namespace for that matter)?

Comment: @barakmanos - What's wrong with namespaces? The standard library is huge and it is there to help you. Use it! Don't *ever* do `using namespace std`.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, is there any way to avoid using the **functionality** provided by `std`?

Comment: @barakmanos - Sure. You could write your own templates that do the exact same thing as the templates already provided by the standard library. Why would you want to do this unless forced to (e.g., by not having C++11)?

Comment: @barakmanos Well you can write the functionalities yourself, but it will still be template programing.